# add array to matrix(multidimensional) array in php

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

i would like to add array to a matrix(multidimensional) array.

e.g.

```
 $a = array ('a','b','1');

 $b = array ('b','c','1');

 $matrix += $a;

 $matrix += $b;

 //data in $matrix = array( array('a','b','1'), array('b','c','1') );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think array_push is what you're after.

```
$a = array ('a','b','1');

$b = array ('b','c','1');

$matrix = array();

array_push($matrix, $a);
array_push($matrix, $b);

var_dump($matrix);
```

You can also simply add it with square brackets which will do the same thing:

```
$a = array ('a','b','1');

$b = array ('b','c','1');

$matrix = array();

$matrix[] = $a;
$matrix[] = $b;

var_dump($matrix);
```

Pushes $a in to $matrix, and then the 2nd line pushed $b, you are then presented with:

```
    array (size=2)
    0 =>
        array (size=3)
            0 => string 'a' (length=1)
            1 => string 'b' (length=1)
            2 => string '1' (length=1)
            1 =>
        array (size=3)
            0 => string 'b' (length=1)
            1 => string 'c' (length=1)
            2 => string '1' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use :

```
$a = array ('a','b','1');
$b = array ('b','c','1');
$matrix = array();
$matrix[] = $a;
$matrix[] = $b;
```

This will give you :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => c
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add 2 array in $matrix:

```
$a = array ('a','b','1');
$b = array ('b','c','1');
$matrix = array();
$matrix[] = $a;
$matrix[] = $b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```
<?php

$a = array ('a','b','1');

$b = array ('b','c','1');

$matrix = [];
array_push($matrix, $a);
array_push($matrix, $b);

print_r($matrix);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => c
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use [array merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$a = array ('a','b','1');
$b = array ('b','c','1');
$matrix = array_merge($a, $b);
print_r($matrix);

//Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => 1 [3] => b [4] => c [5] => 1 )
```